# How do I create centralized Ruby environment variables?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, environment-variables

I have multiple Ruby servers, and I need to modify environment variables on each of them, at the same time.

I'm on AWS EC2 with Debian instances. How can I update my variables from a centralized server?

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Perhaps Capistrano's console will help with this.  https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano#console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of tools that you can use: capistrano, knife (chef), puppet...

There is a long list at "[Deployment Automation](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/deployment_automation)".

Comment: Thanks for the list. It's perfect.